# How do I parse subjectAltName extension data using pyasn1?

Tags: python, ssl, x509, asn.1

I have some data that pyOpenSSL gave me, `'0\r\x82\x0bexample.com'`.  This should be the value of a subjectAltName X509 extension.  I tried to encode the necessary parts of the ASN1 specification for this extension using pyasn1 (and based on one of the pyasn1 examples):

```
from pyasn1.type import univ, constraint, char, namedtype

from pyasn1.codec.der.decoder import decode

MAX = 64

class DirectoryString(univ.Choice):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
        namedtype.NamedType(
            'teletexString', char.TeletexString().subtype(
                subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(1, MAX))),
        namedtype.NamedType(
            'printableString', char.PrintableString().subtype(
                subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(1, MAX))),
        namedtype.NamedType(
            'universalString', char.UniversalString().subtype(
                subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(1, MAX))),
        namedtype.NamedType(
            'utf8String', char.UTF8String().subtype(
                subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(1, MAX))),
        namedtype.NamedType(
            'bmpString', char.BMPString().subtype(
                subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(1, MAX))),
        namedtype.NamedType(
            'ia5String', char.IA5String().subtype(
                subtypeSpec=constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(1, MAX))),
        )


class AttributeValue(DirectoryString):
    pass


class AttributeType(univ.ObjectIdentifier):
    pass


class AttributeTypeAndValue(univ.Sequence):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
        namedtype.NamedType('type', AttributeType()),
        namedtype.NamedType('value', AttributeValue()),
        )


class RelativeDistinguishedName(univ.SetOf):
    componentType = AttributeTypeAndValue()

class RDNSequence(univ.SequenceOf):
    componentType = RelativeDistinguishedName()


class Name(univ.Choice):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
        namedtype.NamedType('', RDNSequence()),
        )


class Extension(univ.Sequence):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
        namedtype.NamedType('extnID', univ.ObjectIdentifier()),
        namedtype.DefaultedNamedType('critical', univ.Boolean('False')),
        namedtype.NamedType('extnValue', univ.OctetString()),
        )


class Extensions(univ.SequenceOf):
    componentType = Extension()
    sizeSpec = univ.SequenceOf.sizeSpec + constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(1, MAX)


class GeneralName(univ.Choice):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
        # namedtype.NamedType('otherName', AnotherName()),
        namedtype.NamedType('rfc822Name', char.IA5String()),
        namedtype.NamedType('dNSName', char.IA5String()),
        # namedtype.NamedType('x400Address', ORAddress()),
        namedtype.NamedType('directoryName', Name()),
        # namedtype.NamedType('ediPartyName', EDIPartyName()),
        namedtype.NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', char.IA5String()),
        namedtype.NamedType('iPAddress', univ.OctetString()),
        namedtype.NamedType('registeredID', univ.ObjectIdentifier()),
        )


class GeneralNames(univ.SequenceOf):
    componentType = GeneralName()
    sizeSpec = univ.SequenceOf.sizeSpec + constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(1, MAX)


class SubjectAltName(GeneralNames):
    pass

print decode('0\r\x82\x0bexample.com', asn1Spec=GeneralNames())
```

Clearly I got a little bored near the end and didn't fully specify the `GeneralName` type.  However, the test string should contain a `dNSName`, not one of the skipped values, so I hope it doesn't matter.

When the program is run, it fails with an error I'm not able to interpret:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x509.py", line 94, in <module>
    print decode('0\r\x82\x0bexample.com', asn1Spec=GeneralNames())
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/pyasn1/v1/codec/ber/decoder.py", line 493, in __call__
    length, stGetValueDecoder, decodeFun
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/pyasn1/v1/codec/ber/decoder.py", line 202, in valueDecoder
    substrate, asn1Spec
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/pyasn1/v1/codec/ber/decoder.py", line 453, in __call__
    __chosenSpec.getTypeMap().has_key(tagSet):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/pyasn1/v1/type/univ.py", line 608, in getTypeMap
    return Set.getComponentTypeMap(self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/pyasn1/v1/type/univ.py", line 535, in getComponentTypeMap
    def getComponentTypeMap(self): return self._componentType.getTypeMap(1)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/pyasn1/v1/type/namedtype.py", line 126, in getTypeMap
    'Duplicate type %s in map %s'%(k,self.__typeMap)
pyasn1.error.PyAsn1Error: Duplicate type TagSet(Tag(tagClass=0, tagFormat=0, tagId=22)) in map {TagSet(Tag(tagClass=0, tagFormat=0, tagId=22)): IA5String()}
```

Any tips on where I went wrong and how to successfully parse this extension type with pyasn1 would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I posted this question on the pyasn1-users list and Ilya Etingof (the author of pyasn1) pointed out my mistake.  In brief, each `NamedType` in `GeneralName.componentType` needs to be given tag information.  This is done with the `subtype` method.  For example, instead of:

```
namedtype.NamedType('rfc822Name', char.IA5String()),
```

the definition should be:

```
namedtype.NamedType('rfc822Name', char.IA5String().subtype(
        implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext,
                            tag.tagFormatSimple, 1))),
```

where `1` comes from the ASN.1 definition of *GeneralName*:

```
GeneralName ::= CHOICE {
   otherName                       [0]     OtherName,
   rfc822Name                      [1]     IA5String,
   dNSName                         [2]     IA5String,
   x400Address                     [3]     ORAddress,
   directoryName                   [4]     Name,
   ediPartyName                    [5]     EDIPartyName,
   uniformResourceIdentifier       [6]     IA5String,
   iPAddress                       [7]     OCTET STRING,
   registeredID                    [8]     OBJECT IDENTIFIER
}
```

After defining a tag for each of these fields of the `componentType`, parsing succeeds:

```
(GeneralNames().setComponentByPosition(
    0, GeneralName().setComponentByPosition(1, IA5String('example.com'))), '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Coming in way late with this answer but instead of writing the ASN.1 Schema by hand you can also use the RF2459 module provided in [pyasn1-modules](https://github.com/etingof/pyasn1-modules) (also authored by Ilya Etingof)

Minimally this code should work and will hopefully be enough to get you started on more complex ANS.1 constructs. Make sure you have run `pip install pyasn1`, `pip install pyasn1-modules` and `pip install pyopenssl` otherwise you'll get import errors.

```
# Import pyasn and the proper decode function
import pyasn1
from pyasn1.codec.der.decoder import decode as asn1_decoder

# Import SubjectAltName from rfc2459 module
from pyasn1_modules.rfc2459 import SubjectAltName

# Import native Python type encoder
from pyasn1.codec.native.encoder import encode as nat_encoder

# Import OpenSSL tools for working with certs.
from OpenSSL import crypto
# Read raw certificate file
with open('PATH/TO/CERTIFICATE.crt', 'r') as cert_f:
    raw_cert = cert_f.read()

cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, raw_cert)

# Note this example assumes SubjectAltName is the only Extension for this cert. 
raw_alt_names = cert.get_extension(0).get_data()

decoded_alt_names, _ = asn1_decoder(raw_alt_names, asn1Spec=SubjectAltName())

# Unless a raw string of ASN.1 is what you need encode back to native Python types
py_alt_names = nat_encoder(decoded_alt_names)

# And Finally a plain Python list of UTF-8 encoded strings representing the SubjectAltNames
subject_alt_names = [ x['dNSName'].decode('utf-8') for x in py_alt_names]
```

The output of this will be something like

```
['cdn1.example.com', 'cdn2.example.com']
```

If the cert you are working on has multiple extensions you will need to use [get_extension_count](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.X509.get_extension_count) from the X509 object and [get_short_name](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.X509Extension.get_short_name) from the X509Extension object provided in pyopenssl.